# How to do asynchronous task while defining a permission using angular permission library

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, satellizer, angular-permission, angularjs-1.7

I'm using [angular-permission](https://github.com/RafaelVidaurre/angular-permission) library along with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer).

Following is the state definition for `home`. In that I'm checking whether user is authorized using [angular-permission](https://github.com/RafaelVidaurre/angular-permission).

```
$stateProvider.state('500', home);
var home = {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/home',
  data: {
    permissions: {
      only: ['loggedin',],
      redirectTo: {
        loggedin: 'login',
      },
    }
  },
  templateUrl: 'components/home/home.view.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'
};
```

---

Following is the permission definition for `loggedin`

```
PermPermissionStore.definePermission('loggedin', isAuthenticated);

function isAuthenticated(permissionName, transitionProperties) {
  // check if token is valid.
  if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    return true;
  }
  // if not then refresh token
  return tokenRestService.refresh().then(
    function (response) {
      if (response != null) {
        $auth.setToken(response);
      }
    },
    function (response) {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
  );
}
```

But somewhat it is not working when I'm doing asynchronous call. If I change `isAuthenticated` function as follow, then it is working properly, but I need to refresh token if in case token is expired, otherwise, redirect user to login page.

```
function isAuthenticated(permissionName, transitionProperties) {
  if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

From the [doc](https://github.com/RafaelVidaurre/angular-permission/wiki/Managing-permissions#individual-permissions) of angular-permission:

> Sometimes you will need to call some a back-end api or do some other
>   asynchronous task to check if permission is still valid. For that you
>   can use promises and simply return them from validation function:
>
> ```
> PermPermissionStore
>   // Define user permission calling back-end
>   .definePermission('hasValidSession', /*@ngInject*/function (Session) {
>     // Let's assume that Session service calls backend API via $http and return promise:
>     // -- $q.resolve() means that session is active 
>     // -- $q.reject() means that session expired
>     return Session.checkSession();
>   });
> ```

But when I use a service in the `definePermission`, it simply goes through without any redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the documentation:

> ```
>  -- $q.resolve() means that session is active 
>  -- $q.reject() means that session expired
> ```

Return either resolved or rejected promises to the `.then` method:

```
PermPermissionStore.definePermission('loggedin', isAuthenticated);

function isAuthenticated(permissionName, transitionProperties) {
  // check if token is valid.
  if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    return true;
  }
  // if not then refresh token
  return tokenRestService.refresh().then(
    function (response) {
      if (response != null) {
        $auth.setToken(response);
      }
      return $q.resolve();
    },
    function (response) {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      return $q.reject();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `$http` returns a promise. So do I have to return `$q.resolve()` and `$q.reject()` manually?

Comment: The `.then` method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the **return value** of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)). See [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).